# UNION returning zero rows

Tags: sql, union, teradata

I have created two volatile tables of equal number and labels and types of columns that both return results when selecting them individually, however when I use a UNION statement the query runs and returns a table with zero rows...
Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: The tables would seem to be empty when your `union` runs

Comment: Are you running the individual selects in a different environment or an uncommitted session with uncommitted data whereas the union is running on a different connection or environment?

Comment: No, same environment and same session

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: Since they are volatile tables it is simply a: create multiset volatile table table1 as (select a.* from vol_table1 a union select b.* from vol_table2 b)with data and statistics on commit preserve rows

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason, when I choose the columns individually, instead of select * the union works.
Thanks,
Hannah

Answer (score 0):

Observed the same behavior until I added "on commit preserve rows", and then select * from table1 union select * from table2 started returning records in the same session.

Comment: I always use on commit preserve rows for my volatile tables, thanks!